# Get System last boot time in Java

Tags: java, operating-system

How can I get the last boot time in Java ?
I know I can run a command line in Java but I don't know if all OS can execute the same command line.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a part of the standard Java Runtime Library.  You will need to ask the underlying operating system either through an API call or by invoking a command that can tell you.  These tend not to be portable across systems, so you need to detect the operating system and invoke the appropriate command.

You may want to consider why your program needs to know this.